# Sending $_POST variable with formsubmit

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to setup an internal website that will allow playback and transcoding on video files. I setup a file to keep track of settings. What I'm doing now is setting a dropdown box with the encoder choices. When the user clicks I want to update the settings file, so that it is updated to whatever is selected. Ideally, I would like for the process to not change webpages and just update automatically, this would probably be with ajax.

I have very limited experience with web coding. The problem I'm running into right now is that my code below works, with the exception of the $EncoderType variable.

When I put quotes around `$_POST['encoder_Type']` I end up with an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /var/www/index.php on line 414

Below is my quoted version that I have tried. This is also the line that is giving the error:

> echo $EncoderType = "$_POST['encoder_type']";

```
     echo "<form ";
        echo $EncoderType = $_POST['encoder_type'];         
        echo "action=";                     
        echo exec("sed -i '8 c\EncoderType:$EncoderType:(1-H264 2-WMV8 3-MPEG 4-MPG4v2)' /home/root/settings");
        echo "method='post'>";
        echo '<select name="encoder_type" onChange="this.form.submit()">';
        echo '<option value="1">H264</option>';
        echo '<option value="2">WMV8</option>';
        echo '<option value="3">MPEG2</option>';
        echo '<option value="4">MPG4v2</option>';
        echo '</select>';
     echo '</form>';
```

This is my current output:

```
EncoderType::(1-H264 2-WMV8 3-MPEG 4-MPG4v2)
```

It should read:

```
EncoderType:1:(1-H264 2-WMV8 3-MPEG 4-MPG4v2)
```

Comment: That sounds like you have mis-matched quotes somewhere - can you add the quoted version of the line?

Comment: @andrewsi Updated to reflect the quoted version as well.

Comment: @ernie I updated the question. Line 414 is: echo $EncoderType = "$_POST['encoder_type']";

Comment: I'd also move the exec() code out, and call a separate PHP function that's a wrapper, since it looks like someone could define an arbitrary action and POST it . . .

Comment: This is the third question in as many days I've seen on SO that has a problem that is related to using PHP's embedded variables. Whilst a neat trick once-upon-a-time, it's really one more headache you don't need in PHP.

Comment: @staticsan I'm not sure what you're referring to.  I don't think OP's trying to use an embedded variable (as I don't think $EncoderType even exists), that's just what he/she choose to use for a variable name . . .

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is very limited. but try this:

```
echo "<form ";
    $EncoderType = (int)$_POST['encoder_type'];         
    echo "action=";                     
    echo exec("sed -i '8 c\EncoderType:".$EncoderType.":(1-H264 2-WMV8 3-MPEG 4-MPG4v2)' /home/root/settings");
    echo "method='post'>";
    echo '<select name="encoder_type" onChange="this.form.submit()">';
    echo '<option value="1">H264</option>';
    echo '<option value="2">WMV8</option>';
    echo '<option value="3">MPEG2</option>';
    echo '<option value="4">MPG4v2</option>';
    echo '</select>';
 echo '</form>';
```

Response to your edit (echo $EncoderType = "$_POST['encoder_type']";):
That wont work.

```
<?php $EncoderType = "{$_POST['encoder_type']}";
```

Will work, but since you use EXEC on what seems to be a root account (please don't ever do that), make sure the variable in $_POST is OK or harmless. So I made it like this:

```
<?php $EncoderType = (int)$_POST['encoder_type'];
```

Then you are sure $EncoderType is an integer, and therefore harmless in this case. And remove the echo, I don't think you want to echo the variable on that place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to set the enctype of your form, you should do:

```
echo $EncoderType . "=" . $_POST['encoder_type'];
```

And in that case you probably miss a white space in the following line:

```
echo " action=";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, I think this is what you need:

```
echo "EncoderType='" . $_POST['encoder_type']. "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you're describing two errors.  First, there's the error when you try to assign to $EncoderType, which is the PHP error text you've thrown.

That can be fixed by changing the echo line to read:

```
$EncoderType = $_POST['encoder_type'];
```

Second, you've got an error with your output (the editing of /home/root/settings), where the encoder type isn't in the actual output, which makes sense, as your action will never actually run as far as I can tell - e.g. I don't think you can `exec()` as an action, as the action attribute is where to send the data (i.e. what webpage), not what action to perform.

In your case, I'd write a simple php page, such as "process_action.php" that would look something like:

```
<?php
  $encType = $_POST['encoder_type'];
  // You should probably rewrite the next line to use native PHP, rather than exec()!
  exec("sed -i '8 c\EncoderType:{$encType}:(1-H264 2-WMV8 3-MPEG 4-MPG4v2)' /home/root/settings"; 
?>

<html>
<head/>
<body>
  Changed encoder type to <?php echo $encType ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd also change your submit form to be pure HTML - there's no need for anything dynamic there as far as I can tell, so something of the form:

```
 <form action='process_action.php' method='post'>
      <select name="encoder_type" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">H264</option>
        <option value="2">WMV8</option>
        <option value="3">MPEG2</option>
        <option value="4">MPG4v2</option>
      </select>
 </form>
```